# SBS 2008 - Add user not seeing AD users (reconnecting or creating new mailbox)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

Using SBS 2008 - completely updated.

I was originally trying to create a spam mailbox for quarantine purposes, and when I bring up the "select an existing user" it does not display any of the domain users (other than QB database user accounts installed on their server).  I have tried changing the scope and still nothing.  Searching reveals nothing either.

Then later I noticed that we had (1) disconnected mailbox, and I tried to reconnect it to the AD user - and I got the same results.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "Select an existing user" option will only show user accounts that have no mailboxes associated with them.

So for a spam mailbox like you describe you would need to have already created a user account in Active Directory (eg one named "spammailbox"), or during the New Mailbox wizard create a new account at that time.